# Python: Converted JSON to GeoJSON format (rfc7946) is in Coordinate system WGS84 but has to be Lambert72

Tags: qgis, python, json

I have some code  to convert a JSON object requested from an API to a GeoJSON object based on the standard rfc7946. You see the data requested from the API was not actually a GeoJSON formated so I had to convert it to Code is here below:

```
def process_location_data(location_json, sper_years : int):
    # assigning variable to store geometry details
    geometry_details = location_json.get("location").get("geometry")
    # includes city and location_coordinates
    location_details = {
        "cities": location_json.get("location").get("cities"),
        "coordinate": location_json.get("location").get("coordinate"),
    }
    # TODO: You declare the gipod_id var here. What is it used for? -sg
    gipod_id = location_json.get("gipodId")

    # EndDateTime
    end_datetime = location_json.get("endDateTime")

    # Sper_date_time
    sper_date_time = sper_berekening(location_json.get("endDateTime"), sper_years)
    # sper_year_period
    sper_year_period = sper_years
    # StartDateTime
    start_datetime = location_json.get("startDateTime")
    # State
    state = location_json.get("state")
    # type
    # NOTE -> Modified "type" to "loc_type".  "type" is an internal Python
    # keyword, and should
    # never be used as a variable.  -sg
    loc_type = location_json.get("type")
    # owner
    owner = location_json.get("owner")
    # lastestUpdate
    lastestUpdate = location_json.get("latestUpdate")
    # reference
    reference = location_json.get("reference")
    # gipodId
    gipod_id = location_json.get("gipodId")
    # cities
    cities = location_json.get("location").get("cities")
    # adding all these details into another dict

    properties = {
        "gipodId": gipod_id,
        "StartDate": start_datetime,
        "EndDate": end_datetime,
        "lastestUpdate":  lastestUpdate,
        "Sper_year": sper_year_period,
        "sperdate": sper_date_time,
        "state": state,
        "type": loc_type,
        "owner": owner,
        "reference": reference,
        "location": location_details,
    }
    # creating the final dict to be returned.
    geojson_data_point = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": geometry_details,
        "properties": properties,
    }
    return geojson_data_point


def process_all_location_data(all_location_points, sper_year: int):
    # For all the points in the location details we will
    # create the feature collection
    feature_collection = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [],
    }  # creates dict with zero features.
    for data_point in all_location_points:
        feature_collection.get("features").append(process_location_data(data_point, sper_year))
    return feature_collection
```

This can be read in QGIS just fine, the problem is however that the GeoJSON is in WGS84. While in reality it should be Lambert 72 from the start.

[image]

Because we requested the data is in Lambert 72 (ESPG:31370), heck the CRS is even referenced as Lambert 72. The coordinates clearly are in Lambert 72. See the JSON object below. We use Lambert 72 as the standard in our projects, so how do I solve this problem to make sure it is Lambert 72, in my Python Script? Yes I  know we can technically solve this with GDAL, in fact I kind of already have but I need something in can set in the begining.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            134258.77936085,
                            183057.08260379
                        ],
                        [
                            134244.49435718,
                            183065.17760501
                        ],
                        [
                            134235.8006087,
                            183043.27259859
                        ],
                        [
                            134234.37185962,
                            183035.53384814
                        ],
                        [
                            134231.15811069,
                            183027.91509661
                        ],
                        [
                            134229.49185855,
                            183019.22385058
                        ],
                        [
                            134229.84810931,
                            183016.84385332
                        ],
                        [
                            134227.69435794,
                            183002.55759844
                        ],
                        [
                            134226.88436038,
                            182986.11134753
                        ],
                        [
                            134225.4556113,
                            182974.68259844
                        ],
                        [
                            134219.74186046,
                            182962.54009661
                        ],
                        [
                            134226.82435901,
                            182954.10509905
                        ],
                        [
                            134228.01560886,
                            182954.10509905
                        ],
                        [
                            134229.08685977,
                            182953.15259966
                        ],
                        [
                            134255.59083086,
                            182909.58959991
                        ],
                        [
                            134268.68583208,
                            182884.35209686
                        ],
                        [
                            134279.01832873,
                            182869.62709839
                        ],
                        [
                            134291.8758269,
                            182857.00709564
                        ],
                        [
                            134304.97082812,
                            182848.19709808
                        ],
                        [
                            134318.06582934,
                            182839.86459381
                        ],
                        [
                            134324.25832659,
                            182834.86459381
                        ],
                        [
                            134325.44832903,
                            182831.2920993
                        ],
                        [
                            134321.63833147,
                            182827.48459656
                        ],
                        [
                            134288.32833391,
                            182792.01960022
                        ],
                        [
                            134275.99582964,
                            182779.49459869
                        ],
                        [
                            134245.67332751,
                            182732.83959991
                        ],
                        [
                            134223.15082842,
                            182690.10209686
                        ],
                        [
                            134214.5308333,
                            182672.69709808
                        ],
                        [
                            134184.05583102,
                            182627.93460114
                        ],
                        [
                            134141.54333025,
                            182592.75709564
                        ],
                        [
                            134145.11332995,
                            182588.47209961
                        ],
                        [
                            134187.73333269,
                            182626.32959778
                        ],
                        [
                            134217.32832629,
                            182670.68460114
                        ],
                        [
                            134236.13833147,
                            182703.78209717
                        ],
                        [
                            134249.38833147,
                            182729.14959747
                        ],
                        [
                            134264.38833147,
                            182752.48459656
                        ],
                        [
                            134278.67333514,
                            182775.33959991
                        ],
                        [
                            134301.95832354,
                            182802.2920993
                        ],
                        [
                            134329.57833391,
                            182830.38710052
                        ],
                        [
                            134370.92333514,
                            182857.30459625
                        ],
                        [
                            134430.44832903,
                            182845.87709839
                        ],
                        [
                            134455.20832354,
                            182872.30459625
                        ],
                        [
                            134451.87583452,
                            182874.20959503
                        ],
                        [
                            134428.3058272,
                            182848.73459656
                        ],
                        [
                            134369.73333269,
                            182860.86459381
                        ],
                        [
                            134331.63833147,
                            182835.86459381
                        ],
                        [
                            134304.97082812,
                            182851.57959778
                        ],
                        [
                            134283.88708789,
                            182869.41334945
                        ],
                        [
                            134276.38708789,
                            182879.88959915
                        ],
                        [
                            134264.98833758,
                            182900.49709732
                        ],
                        [
                            134247.22083575,
                            182934.61584884
                        ],
                        [
                            134233.35083682,
                            182956.91334945
                        ],
                        [
                            134231.32708651,
                            182961.91334945
                        ],
                        [
                            134233.58958728,
                            182967.98459655
                        ],
                        [
                            134234.38708789,
                            182978.96709854
                        ],
                        [
                            134235.45833499,
                            182985.27709991
                        ],
                        [
                            134236.88708789,
                            182986.58585006
                        ],
                        [
                            134236.23208529,
                            183005.64584762
                        ],
                        [
                            134238.13708789,
                            183008.5033496
                        ],
                        [
                            134239.92333514,
                            183021.4795993
                        ],
                        [
                            134251.28583438,
                            183048.63334686
                        ],
                        [
                            134258.77936085,
                            183057.08260379
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "type": "Polygon",
                "crs": {
                    "type": "name",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Please cut/paste your dilation from the area reserved for your question into the area reserved for answers to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your GeoJSON is not formatted correctly. The CRS definition is nested too deep. It should be formatted in the following way, and QGIS will be able to read the CRS info properly.  Copy the following into your IDE, save it as a geojson, and it will be read by QGIS.

Make sure to check the formatting of the geojson in Python before you export it (the dict containing your CRS info should be separate from the array of features).

Note: if you export a feature collection, then you might want to create it using following method:

```
crs = {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
    }
}

myFC =FeatureCollection(features ,crs=crs)
```

Here, `features` is your array of features.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
        }},
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {"type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            134258.77936085,
                            183057.08260379
                        ],
                        [
                            134244.49435718,
                            183065.17760501
                        ],
                        [
                            134235.8006087,
                            183043.27259859
                        ],
                        [
                            134234.37185962,
                            183035.53384814
                        ],
                        [
                            134231.15811069,
                            183027.91509661
                        ],
                        [
                            134229.49185855,
                            183019.22385058
                        ],
                        [
                            134229.84810931,
                            183016.84385332
                        ],
                        [
                            134227.69435794,
                            183002.55759844
                        ],
                        [
                            134226.88436038,
                            182986.11134753
                        ],
                        [
                            134225.4556113,
                            182974.68259844
                        ],
                        [
                            134219.74186046,
                            182962.54009661
                        ],
                        [
                            134226.82435901,
                            182954.10509905
                        ],
                        [
                            134228.01560886,
                            182954.10509905
                        ],
                        [
                            134229.08685977,
                            182953.15259966
                        ],
                        [
                            134255.59083086,
                            182909.58959991
                        ],
                        [
                            134268.68583208,
                            182884.35209686
                        ],
                        [
                            134279.01832873,
                            182869.62709839
                        ],
                        [
                            134291.8758269,
                            182857.00709564
                        ],
                        [
                            134304.97082812,
                            182848.19709808
                        ],
                        [
                            134318.06582934,
                            182839.86459381
                        ],
                        [
                            134324.25832659,
                            182834.86459381
                        ],
                        [
                            134325.44832903,
                            182831.2920993
                        ],
                        [
                            134321.63833147,
                            182827.48459656
                        ],
                        [
                            134288.32833391,
                            182792.01960022
                        ],
                        [
                            134275.99582964,
                            182779.49459869
                        ],
                        [
                            134245.67332751,
                            182732.83959991
                        ],
                        [
                            134223.15082842,
                            182690.10209686
                        ],
                        [
                            134214.5308333,
                            182672.69709808
                        ],
                        [
                            134184.05583102,
                            182627.93460114
                        ],
                        [
                            134141.54333025,
                            182592.75709564
                        ],
                        [
                            134145.11332995,
                            182588.47209961
                        ],
                        [
                            134187.73333269,
                            182626.32959778
                        ],
                        [
                            134217.32832629,
                            182670.68460114
                        ],
                        [
                            134236.13833147,
                            182703.78209717
                        ],
                        [
                            134249.38833147,
                            182729.14959747
                        ],
                        [
                            134264.38833147,
                            182752.48459656
                        ],
                        [
                            134278.67333514,
                            182775.33959991
                        ],
                        [
                            134301.95832354,
                            182802.2920993
                        ],
                        [
                            134329.57833391,
                            182830.38710052
                        ],
                        [
                            134370.92333514,
                            182857.30459625
                        ],
                        [
                            134430.44832903,
                            182845.87709839
                        ],
                        [
                            134455.20832354,
                            182872.30459625
                        ],
                        [
                            134451.87583452,
                            182874.20959503
                        ],
                        [
                            134428.3058272,
                            182848.73459656
                        ],
                        [
                            134369.73333269,
                            182860.86459381
                        ],
                        [
                            134331.63833147,
                            182835.86459381
                        ],
                        [
                            134304.97082812,
                            182851.57959778
                        ],
                        [
                            134283.88708789,
                            182869.41334945
                        ],
                        [
                            134276.38708789,
                            182879.88959915
                        ],
                        [
                            134264.98833758,
                            182900.49709732
                        ],
                        [
                            134247.22083575,
                            182934.61584884
                        ],
                        [
                            134233.35083682,
                            182956.91334945
                        ],
                        [
                            134231.32708651,
                            182961.91334945
                        ],
                        [
                            134233.58958728,
                            182967.98459655
                        ],
                        [
                            134234.38708789,
                            182978.96709854
                        ],
                        [
                            134235.45833499,
                            182985.27709991
                        ],
                        [
                            134236.88708789,
                            182986.58585006
                        ],
                        [
                            134236.23208529,
                            183005.64584762
                        ],
                        [
                            134238.13708789,
                            183008.5033496
                        ],
                        [
                            134239.92333514,
                            183021.4795993
                        ],
                        [
                            134251.28583438,
                            183048.63334686
                        ],
                        [
                            134258.77936085,
                            183057.08260379
                        ]
                    ]
                ]}
              }]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from @the_dark_side I have solved the problem, I had to change this part of the code to this:

```
def process_all_location_data(all_location_points, sper_year: int):
    # For all the points in the location details we will
    # create the feature collection
    feature_collection = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
        }},
        "features": [],
    }  # creates dict with zero features.
    for data_point in all_location_points:
        feature_collection.get("features").append(process_location_data(data_point, sper_year))
    return feature_collection
```